# What's the difference between these haskell function definitions?

Tags: haskell

I don't really understand what the problem is with the second one...

```
--ver1
mymin [a]=a
mymin (x:y:xs) = mymin ((if x < y then x else y):xs)

--ver2
mymin [a]=a
mymin (x:y:xs) = mymin ((
    | x<y  x
    | otherwise  y
):xs)
```

Comment: the 2nd one is not valid Haskell.

Comment: The second case is almost valid syntax with `MultiWayIf`: `if | x < y -> x; | otherwise -> y`. Of course if your `if` only has two branches, just use a regular `if`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the reason the second one *don't work* is simply that the *syntax* is not valid Haskell.

*Guards*  (`| x < y ..`) are no syntax replacement for `if` - they only work in specific places. For example here you have to use them like this:

```
mymin [a] = a
mymin (x:y:xs)
  | x < y     = mymin (x:xs)
  | otherwise = mymin (y:xs)
```

there is a very nice explanation on this in [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) (look for **Guards, Guards!**) in case you want to know more